# How to get the weights from regression coefficient(path coefficients) in structural equation model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, regression-coefficients, structural-equation-modeling

I am reading about the structural equation model(SEM) and I have a use case that is going to be needing it. In my use-case, I don't have latent variables, so we can think of it as a Path analysis.

The output from SEM gives us couple of things p-value and Estimates are most important. p-value gives us significance of the feature, while Estimate gives us some quantitative figure that tells us how a certain feature impacts on the other dependent feature.

Sample output from a structural equation model:-

```
   lval  op rval    Estimate    Std. Err   z-value   p-value
0    a   ~    d    0.214797    0.405306  0.529962  0.596138
1    b   ~    d    0.197167    0.374708  0.526187  0.598758
2    c   ~    d   -0.608275    0.419378 -1.450421  0.146941
3    c  ~~    c  199.797329  126.362926  1.581139  0.113846
4    a  ~~    a  186.614202  118.025184  1.581139  0.113846
5    b  ~~    b  159.501184  100.877406  1.581139  0.113846
```

My variables in my use case look like this:-

[image]

In the above diagram, all the variables are measurable variables and the Deposit is dependent variables, while other variables are independent. The values written are the "Estimate" values obtained from the SEM, which are also called regression coefficients.

My question and requirements:-

1. I basically need to find if we can interpret these "Estimate" values(Regression coefficient) as "weights" of those feature on how they are impacting the dependent variable?
2. Can I sum up all the coefficients like this `2.44+1.32+0.65+0.32 = 4.73`, and then to get weightage of each feature, later do (estimate of variable x)/(sum of all coefficients), for first variable Var 1 = 2.44/4.73 = 0.51 ?

I basically need some way I can get these estimates to be converted weights, so when I allocate the Dependent variable "Deposit" = say 100 million, I can allocate/distribute it to the independent variables in proportion to their impact on deposit.

Structural equation model is something I am asked to focus, but if this can be achieved in some other ways, I am more than thankful to hear them as well.

Comment: I don't think the sum of coefficients is a meaningful quantity, but you can obtain coefficients using `coef(fit)`, just as you can with `lm` objects.  In fact, if you are only running a univariate regression model, I think there is no advantage to using SEM over OLS regression with `lm()`.  But your output appears to see `d` (righthand side) as the predictor of (lefthandside) outcomes `a`, `b`, and `c`.  Check that your syntax regresses outcomes on predictors (`DV ~ IV1 + IV2`), not the other way around.

Comment: @Terrence I totally agree that SEM doesn't really make much sense here in my use case but client is demanding it so cannot much be done. So, I ended up with this, solution, since SEM without latent was just OLS, I standardized the data using sem's inspect(std_est = true), now, since that data was in same scale, the coefficients becomes more comparable. I forced coefficents to be positive using nnls. Then, I took weights like a/(a+b+c+d) and did the value allocation of the deposits according to their respective weights.

Comment: As long as you are only using point estimates from that standardized solution, I don't see a problem.  If you are trying to draw inferences, then it is not good to analyze sample-standardized data.  The standard errors will be underestimated, inflating the Type I error rates, because the residual variances should not be freely estimated (rather fixed to 1 minus the explained variance).  https://doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.105.2.317